# How to get the Values that is inside First Element and Second Element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the Values that is  inside First Element and Second Element from

### Update (due to wrong edit in Question)

```
var data = {
"0": [
    "The VehicleNumber has already been taken."
],
"2": [
    "The VehicleCode has already been taken."
]}
```

i.e.,

First = The 0 has already been taken.

Second = The 2 has already been taken.

Comment: You do realize that you're not dealing with an array here, but rather you're working with an _object_. The object has 2 properties (`x` and `y`), which can be accessed either using strings (`varName['x']`) or the dot notation (`varName.x`), each of these properties is assigned an array, which you can access using the numeric indexes (`varName.x[0]`)

Answer (score 1):

This is the `JSON` object. To get any value from it you need to know the `key name` eg:- `jsonObj["x"]` and `jsonObj["y"]`.

However if you don't know the key name then  iterate over it as:-

```
$.each(jsonObj,function(k,v){

//get value by using v or jsonObj[k];

});
```

**update  in response to your fiddle**

```
var data={};
data["0"]=["The VehicleNumber field is required."];
data["1"]=["The NumberSeats field is required."];
data["2"]=["The VehicleCode field is required."];
data["3"]=["The MaximumAllowed field is required."];
data["4"]=["The City field is required."];
data["5"]=["The State field is required."];
data["6"]=["The Phone field is required."];
data["7"]=["The Insurance field is required."];
data["9"]=["The Address field is required."];

alert (data[1]);
```

check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/qbjbke03/8/

Comment: where should i give the each loop ?

Comment: The place where you want to access the value    var jsonObj ={
    "x": [ "The 0 has already been taken." ],
    "y": [ "The 2 has already been taken." ]
}  and then apply the for-each loop ..

Comment: Someone has changed the question without my knowledge which changes the question, kindly check the value of data pls

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
console.log(myObj["y"][0] + " " + myObj["x"][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = '{
    "0": [
        "The VehicleNumber field is required."
    ],
    "1": [
        "The NumberSeats field is required."
    ],
    "2": [
        "The VehicleCode field is required."
    ],
    "3": [
        "The MaximumAllowed field is required."
    ],
    "4": [
        "The City field is required."
    ],
    "5": [
        "The State field is required."
    ],
    "6": [
        "The Phone field is required."
    ],
    "7": [
        "The Insurance field is required."
    ],
    "9": [
        "The Address field is required."
    ]
}';
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert (data[0]);
    alert (data[1]);
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbjbke03/7/)**

Comment: What you want with separate first and second?

Comment: I just need the values inside it ie., The 0 has already been taken,, If i have have more elements i.e., x,y,z,a,b,c., It shows display all the Messages

Comment: Kindly check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qbjbke03/3/ , this is the format i have

Comment: Yes, it works, But i while i try to alert all the data[0], data[1] it is showing only the first one http://jsfiddle.net/qbjbke03/10/

Comment: Have you check posted example?

Answer (score 0):

The construct you mentioned in your question is not an array, but an object.

To print all the values of arrays inside your object, you may use -

```
var data = {
    "x": [ "The 0 has already been taken." ],
    "y": [ "The 2 has already been taken." ]
}
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     console.log("First=",data[key][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is considering each letter as array i.e. T|h|e..like that

Comment: You sure? I have checked this code. Here's the output:
`First= The 0 has already been taken.
First= The 2 has already been taken`

Comment: Someone updated my question kindly check the value of the **var data** in my question